# How do I implement cloudinary inside my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, cloudinary

In this code I can use local videos to stream but how do I use cloudinary to serve my videos. I have tried to replace the `filepath` to cloudinary video `url` but it didn't work. CAn anyone please help me out on this part?

```
const http=require('http'); 
const fs=require("fs"); 
const path=require("path"); 


const server=http.createServer((req, res)=>{ 
    // return res.end(req.url+req.method); 
    if(req.method==='GET' && req.url==="/"){ 
        /*we will send a index.html page when 
        user visits "/" endpoint*/
        /*index.html will have video component 
        that displays the video*/
        
        fs.createReadStream(path.resolve( 
                        "index.html")).pipe(res); 
        return; 
    } 
    //if video content is requesting 
    if(req.method==='GET' && req.url==="/video"){ 
        const filepath = path.resolve("video1.mp4"); 
        const stat = fs.statSync(filepath) 
        const fileSize = stat.size 
        const range = req.headers.range 
        /*when we seek the video it will put 
        range header to the request*/
        /*if range header exists send some 
            part of video*/
        if (range) { 
            //range format is "bytes=start-end", 
            const parts = 
                range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-"); 
            

            console.log(parts);
            const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10) 
            /*in some cases end may not exists, if its 
                        not exists make it end of file*/
                        console.log(start);
            const end = 
                parts[1] ?parseInt(parts[1], 10) :fileSize - 1 

                console.log(end);
            
            //chunk size is what the part of video we are sending. 
            const chunksize = (end - start) + 1 
            /*we can provide offset values as options to 
        the fs.createReadStream to read part of content*/
            const file = fs.createReadStream(filepath, {start, end}) 
            
            const head = { 
                'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`, 
                'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 
                'Content-Length': chunksize, 
                'Content-Type': 'video/mp4', 
            } 
            /*we should set status code as 206 which is 
                    for partial content*/
            // because video is continuosly fetched part by part 
            res.writeHead(206, head); 
        file.pipe(res); 
            
        }else{ 
        
        //if not send the video from start. 
        /* anyway html5 video player play content 
        when sufficient frames available*/
        // It doesn't wait for the entire video to load. 
        
        const head = { 
            'Content-Length': fileSize, 
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4', 
        } 
        res.writeHead(200, head); 
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res); 
        } 
    } 
    /*if anything other than handler routes then send 
    400 status code, is for bad request*/
    else{ 
        res.writeHead(400); 
        res.end("bad request"); 
    } 
}) 

/*check if system has environment variable 
for the port, otherwise defaults to 3000*/
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

//start the server 
server.listen(PORT, () => { 
console.log(`server listening on port:${PORT}`); 
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Are you receiving an error response from Cloudinary's API? If so, what is the error? If not, is there an error in your own environment? Do you get a stacktrace for the error?

Comment: I am not using Cloudinary API, cause I am just testing is it working with extrernal url or not.

Comment: const stat = fs.statSync("https://res.cloudinary.com/manasubuntu/video/upload/v1613039225/video1_novr8l.mp4")

Comment: And what error do you receive when trying to load that URL? Is there a typo in your commend or are you also missing the protocol identifier in your actual URL string? (the `http://` or `https://` part may be required by `fs.statSync` )

Comment: It didn't work.